# Missing characters in displaying UTF that written to file

Tags: php, html, file-io

I am trying to input some Vietnamese language from text box to my file then read from that file and display in another page.

The display part is working well as I tried to copy, paste some Vietnamese directly to file and test the displaying. However the writing part some how not right, because when I try input some Vietnamese and test at the display, it will miss some characters at some places. Here is the code I am using to input to file:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <body>
        <form name="form" method="post">
        <style type="text/css"> 
        .inputtext { width: 550px; height: 550px; } 
        </style> 
            <input type="text" name="text_box" class="inputtext" size="250"/>
            <input type="submit" id="search-submit" value="SAVE" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['text_box'])) { //only do file operations when appropriate
        $a = $_POST['text_box'];
        $myFile = mb_convert_encoding("test.txt", "UTF-8", "auto");
    $data = mb_convert_encoding($a, 'UTF-8', "auto");
        $fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
    fwrite($fh,utf8_encode($data));
        fclose($fh);
    }
?>
```

So how is the right way to write UTF8 (or any multi language) to file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you make sure all your pages are already using UTF-8, then the solution would be: Do nothing special with the file, simply write the string (which already is UTF-8) to the file.

So now you need to find out how to make everything in your page UTF-8. You should start sending a `Content-type` header: `header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`

Comment: I already added :header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); in the php code at the display as you suggested, and removed the processing in the input, just a normal file input. But it show worse, there are square block in displaying and the display look more messy.

Comment: Ok, I corrected the solution, I put: <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
at the input file also. Previously, I only have that in the reading (display file). So what you suggested is correct. Thank you, that is the answer for my question.